# How can I use SQLAlchemy model with Django ModelForm

Tags: django, sqlalchemy, django-forms

I have models defined in SQLAlchemy for a django application. Can I use Django ModelForm with SQLAlchemy models?
By doing so it throws an error that there is no _meta defined in the SQLAlchemy model...

```
from sqlalchemy import Column, Integer, String
from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import declarative_base

Base = declarative_base()

class SomeClass(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'some_table'
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    name =  Column(String(50))

# Forms.py

from django.forms import ModelForm

class SomeClassForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = SomeClass

# views.py
form = SomeClassForm() # raises error type object 'SomeClass' has no attribute '_meta'
```

Please note this is all example.

Comment: pls show your code

Comment: added sample code to illustrate the problem